# AWS Lambda Node. Js How to use Secrets Manager to connect to the database

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I created a PostgreSQL database instance in the AWS console, and then created a user name and password for Secrets Manager to manage the PostgreSQL database,Please tell me about the node in lambda Js how to use Secrets Manager to connect to the database and query. I'm a novice, and I'm confused about how to implement this function. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

here the official documentation on how to create new secret from lambda
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-secrets-manager/classes/createsecretcommand.html

Here the the official documentation on how to retrieve the credentials storage in secrets manager:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-secrets-manager/classes/getsecretvaluecommand.html

Here the sniped code:

```
import {SecretsManagerClient, GetSecretValueCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";

const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
    region: 'us-west-1'
});

const command = new GetSecretValueCommand({
    SecretId: process.env.RDS_SECRET_NAME,//lambda env with the secret name
    VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT"
});
let sql;

try {
    const response = await client.send(command);
    const secrets = JSON.parse(response['SecretString']);

    // noinspection JSUnresolvedReference
    sql = postgres({
        hostname: secrets.dbhost,
        username: secrets.username,
        password: secrets.password
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
}
```